# Best practice for handling data types from 3rd party libraries in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

I'm just getting into my first real Haskell project of size (a web app), and I'm starting to run into issues with types from 3rd party libraries leaking all over my code. Here is a quick example:

My `Parser` module imports `Test.Parsec`, and the exports a function (`parseConfig`) that returns `Either ParseError DbConfig`, where `ParseError` is a data type defined in the `Parsec` library (`DbConfig` is a custom data type for my app, not shown for brevity).

```
-- Parser.hs
module Parser where

import Text.Parsec

parseConfig :: String -> Either ParseError DbConfig
parseConfig = parse ...
```

Later, I want to use my `parseConfig` function, but in order to use it, I have to import `Text.Parsec` again so that I have access to the `ParseError` type.

```
-- Api.hs
module Api where

import Parser
import Text.Parsec

getConfigFromBody :: Object -> Either ParseError DbConfig
getConfigFromBody = parseConfig . (...)
```

This is not only a hassle as far as managing imports goes, but also a poor separation of concerns, so right of the bat I know this isn't the best way to do it. My question is, what is the best practice for managing this issue? Would making a type synonym be ideal?

```
type ConfigParseError = ParseError

parseConfig :: String -> Either ConfigParseError DbConfig
parseConfig = parse ...
```

This seems reasonable insofar as keeping the `Parsec` the dependency internal to my `Parser` module, but aliasing library types seems like a strange pattern to use by default.

So my question is, how do larger Haskell apps or libraries handle this? Is there a general technique for managing data types from 3rd party libraries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not ready to give a nice list of best practises, but for starters if you want to keep stuff sanely organized, use explicit exports instead of just exporting everything, e.g:

```
module Parser
  ( parseConfig
  ) where
...
```

Explicit exports also allow you to reexport your imports, e.g.

```
module Parser
  ( parseConfig
  , ParseError(..)
  ) where
...
```

After that you can just `import Parser`, and have `ParseError` available as if it was defined inside `Parser`.

I think this should solve your immediate problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So that definitely makes a lot of sense and helps. It still feels a little weird, mainly because my module is exposing a data type from  a 3rd party module. If I wanted to swap out my parsing library, ideally I'd only have to change it in my parser, and no other module would have to care or even notice the change.

Comment: Well, if you want to be able to swap parsing library, you shouldn't use library specific ParseError as an output of your parsing function. If you don't use it, then your problem would also be solved as there'll be nothing to reexport.

Comment: So what would that look like? Would the mean creating my own error, catching any `ParseError`s, and then instead returning my own error type? I guess that's what I what sort of wondering in the first place - is that a standard practice?

Comment: I don't think there is a standard practise here, but providing your own error type makes a lot of sense. For example if your config file consists of statements in a format "key = value" where key starts with [a-z] the user of your module would prefer to get a specific error `InvalidKey "1mykey"` rather than meaningless (in terms of DBConfig) Parsec's message.